# Canvas draw color inside drawable. Dont touch transparent part of image

Tags: android, canvas, draw

I have a drawable with transparent left and right parts. I need to draw some progress inside it. [image]

```
startDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, startDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            startDrawable.draw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            Path path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(0, 0);
            path.lineTo(startDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2, 0);
            path.lineTo(startDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight());
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

But unfortunately this code fill transparent parts too and it looks like black rectangle.

I want to see something like this. Does it possible to draw black color only inside not trasparent part of image ??
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two different Bitmaps:

1. one that includes your normal background, lines, shapes and any draw you want (be sure to stay INSIDE your choosed bounds)
2. one that is the shape used to CUT the previous one via "Paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.xxxxxxx))" method (do a "PorterDuffXfermode" search on Google Images to see all mixes possibilities)

In this way you are free to draw what you want in a normal rectangular/squared Bitmap, and at the end you apply a Mask (over the whole Bitmap) using a free shape (triangular, circular, etc..). Same tecnique is used to create a circular picture starting from the original rectangular version.

For example this code creates a rounded version of a rectangular Bitmap:

```
@Nullable
public static Bitmap getRoundedBitmap(@Nullable final Bitmap bmp, final int radius) {
    if ((bmp == null) || (radius < 1)) return null;
    Bitmap cBitmap;
    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
        float cSmallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
        float cFactor = cSmallest / radius;
        try {
            cBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth() / cFactor), (int)(bmp.getHeight() / cFactor), true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            cBitmap = null;
        }
    } else cBitmap = bmp;

    if (cBitmap == null) return null;

    final Bitmap cOutput = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas cCanvas = new Canvas(cOutput);

    final Paint cPaint = new Paint();
    final Rect cRect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

    cPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    cPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    cPaint.setDither(true);
    cPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    cCanvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    cPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    cCanvas.drawCircle(radius / 2f, radius / 2f, radius / 2f, cPaint);
    cPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

      //draws the rectangular Bitmap and use the special Paint object that has the circular "mask" set
    cCanvas.drawBitmap(cBitmap, cRect, cRect, cPaint);
    return cOutput;
}
```